# How to disable context in Elixir/Phoenix generators and models completely?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Phoenix has a generator:

```
  mix phx.gen.html Accounts User users name:string age:integer
```

I don't want to use a context for my models, neihter do I want to provide its name. How to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the old generators as they were in 1.2 and earlier

```
mix phoenix.gen.html User users name:string age:integer
```

Note: use `phoenix.gen.html` instead of `phx.gen.html`. More at the [Phoenix 1.3 documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phoenix.Gen.Html.html#content).

The 1.3 generators were named differently so that they could be used side by side with the old.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use the `--no-context` flag.

[Generating without a schema or context file](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.Gen.Json.html#module-generating-without-a-schema-or-context-file)

Comment: it won't generate a model at all  then