# Unable to generate html in Phoenix 1.3

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Trying to generate:

```
$ mix phx.gen.html MyModel my_models a b c d:integer
```

And error:

```
  ** (Mix) Expected the schema, "my_models", to be a valid module name

  mix phx.gen.html, phx.gen.json and phx.gen.context expect a
  context module name, followed by singular and plural names of
  the generated resource, ending with any number of attributes.
  For example:

      mix phx.gen.html Accounts User users name:string
      mix phx.gen.json Accounts User users name:string
      mix phx.gen.context Accounts User users name:string

  The context serves as the API boundary for the given resource.
  Multiple resources may belong to a context and a resource may be
  split over distinct contexts (such as Accounts.User and Payments.User).
```

This doesn't work either:

```
$ mix phx.gen.html MyModel my_models a b c d:integer --no-context

$ mix phx.gen.html MyModel my_models a b c d:integer --no-context --no-schema
```

**And even after this  the error remains:**

```
config :my_app, :generators,
    context: false
```

What's up with it?

Comment: Here is a link that explains that documents the change and why context is now a thing:

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.Gen.Html.html

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on `phx.gen.html`:

> #### Generating without a schema or context file
>
> In some cases, you may wish to boostrap HTML templates, controllers,
>   and controller tests, but leave internal implementation of the context
>   or schema to yourself. You can use the --no-context and --no-schema
>   flags for file generation control.

The `--no-context` flag instructs generator to leave implementation of context module to developer but you still need to include name of context module in command like this:

```
mix phx.gen.html MyContext MyModel my_models a b c d:integer --no-context
```

Comment: look at the last part of my question

Comment: I agree it is bit confusing if you are used to other frameworks but that is design decision you can look up [here](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/2137). Also, if you want old behavior you can use `phoenix.gen.html` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49229878/2894148).

Answer (score 1):

to make the above answer a bit clearer,

```
mix phx.gen.html Thebindingcontext MyModel mymodels a b c d:integer
```